# How do I install this console library? visual studio c++

Tags: c++, console

I was about to begin this tutorial: http://www.kathekonta.com/rlguide/article1.html
(you should see it under the implementation section)But then it said I need the  "console library" does anyone know where I can find this?
And if you find it can you tell me how I can install it? :D I really want to get to this
I have learned the basics(variables, loops, pointers, arrays, operators) thanks much if you read this -lopesam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the page, download his source code.  Inside is a folder named ConsoleLibrary.  It contains console.h and console.lib.  You need to know the directory in which you place them.  For better or for worse, I keep all of mine in a single folder.

When you start your project, you'll have to go to (assuming you're using VS) the project options.  (Project->Project Name Properties)  Click VC++ directories and then click include, the down arrow on the right, then edit.  Add the directory in which the .h file is in.  Do the same for libraries and add the directory that .lib is in.  In the properties menu, click the Linker drop down and click on Input and then Additional Dependencies and add Console.lib to the list.

If you get any linker errors like (unresolved external blah blah blah) then you might need to find a console .dll or some other file and put it in your C++ project directory.

If you're not using VS, then at least you can still find the console library in the same place but I'm unfamiliar with linking in other compilers.